# I'm trying to use an image as one of my "li a" but the img and the a's don't stay at the same height .

Tags: html, css

```
<nav class="second-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/cnnTrends-btn-sprite.png"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I'm doing a navbar, the elements are aligned but the img and li a are not in the same height. How can I style it to so everything can be in the same height ?

Comment: Please add your Css also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what your CSS looks like, but assuming what it looks like, you can use the `vertical-align` property on the `nav .image {}` css.

```css
.second-nav {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.second-nav img {
    vertical-align: top; /* Align image with top of li a tags */
    /*
    vertical-align: center; --> Align image with center of li a
    vertical-align: bottom; --> Align image with bottom of li a
    */
}

.second-nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.second-nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.second-nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/so_help.css" type="text/css">
  <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
        <header>
            <nav class="second-nav">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="https://placeimg.com/75/75/any"/></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
 </body>
</html>
```